# Return a random image in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have 6 .png images in my Xcode project (example: image1.png, image2.png., etc.).  I want to create a method that returns a random image from this set of 6 and assigns it to my view's background. I already have a similar method that returns a random color:

```
+(UIColor *)randomColor
{
CGFloat red= (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
CGFloat blue= (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
CGFloat green= (CGFloat)random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];

}
```

my implementation file calls this method like this:

```
UIColor *randomColor=[SoundDetail randomColor];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:randomColor];
```

How can I edit this method to return a random image from my list of 6 and assign it to my background view?
I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 for a universal iOS 5 project.

Thanks!

Comment: arc4random_uniform is better than rand or random, FYI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIImage * randomImage = [ UIImage imageNamed:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%u.png", 1+arc4random_uniform(6) ] ] ;
```

Comment: (assuming your images are image1.png...image7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have UIImages in an NSArray:

```
- (UIImage *)randomImage
{
    NSArray *imagesArray = // array of images;
    return [imagesArray objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % imagesArray.count];
}
```

Assuming you have UIImage names in an NSArray:

```
- (UIImage *)randomImage
{
    NSArray *imagesArray = // array of image names;
    NSString *imageName = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % imagesArray.count];
    return [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```